# I have a problem with preg match offset

Tags: php, regex

This is the pattern. It still gets the first image

```
preg_match_all('!http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui', $content, $matches);

    preg_match_all('/\S+(list|of|bad|words)\S+/i', $content, $bads);

    $filtered = array_values(array_diff($matches[0], $bads[0]));

$varcontent[$i]["content"] = $content;
$varcontent[$i]["images"] = array_unique($filtered);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume when you say "It still gets the first image" you are saying you want to skip the first match? (if not, be more clear)

That would be because the offset is not a "skip to the nth match" argument.  It is a "start at this character position in the string" argument.  So you are telling it to start at the first character in the string, which is effectively the same as not supplying the argument at all.

There's no "convenient" way to say "start at the 2nd match".  It is much easier to just match all and ignore the first match in the $matches array...

Comment: Hi, thanks. How can ignore it in matches array? By starting from matches[2] ?

Comment: no, since you are not capturing anything and since you want the full URL (the full pattern), you will want to look for all your matches in $matches[0]  Your first match will be $match[0][0], 2nd match will be $matches[0][1], 3rd match is $matches[0][2], etc.. so you can do like array_shift($matches[0]) to remove the first match, or just start counting at $matches[0][1]

Comment: I suggest you use the following: echo "<pre>";print_r($matches); so you can see the structure of your $matches array

Comment: I updated my question with a block of my code.. I think array_shift will do the trick. I tried it next to array values with error.